# angular2 material - md-error and username does not exists from a server call

Tags: angular2-forms

This is my login form.  If a user puts in a wrong username and does not exists on the server then how do I use md-error to display message?

E.g.

Here is the json I get back for auth from a submit:

```
   {is_username: false, status: false}
```

Here is how I set up my form:

```
           this.myForm = fb.group({
                username: ['',[Validators.required]],
                password: ['',[Validators.required]]
            })
```

Here is my HTML:

```
          <md-input-container>
              <input mdInput type="email" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" formControlName="username" style="width: 300px;outline: none;">
              <md-error *ngIf="myForm.get('username').hasError('required')">Username is required</md-error>
              <md-error *ngIf="myForm.get('username').hasError('username_exists')">Username does exist</md-error>
          </md-input-container>
```

So..how do I trigger a md-error message if is_username is false?

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing server side validation like this.

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput type="email" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" formControlName="username" style="width: 300px;outline: none;">
    <md-error *ngIf="myForm.get('username').hasError('required')">Username is required</md-error>
    <md-error *ngIf="myForm.controls['username'].hasError('username_exists')">{{myForm.controls['username'].errors['username_exists']}}</md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

Then, set the error after you get the response from the server.

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setErrors

```
this.myForm.controls['username'].setErrors({
  'username_exists': 'Username does exist'
});
```

I typically return validation error messages from the server as well, which could be used here.